# Telegram: get fileid from telegram client

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, telegram, telegram-bot, mtproto

Telegram bots use `fileid` to download a file. How can I get this `fileid` from Telegram client (My Unofficial version) ? Files in `mtproto` have [this location class](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/fileLocation) that indicates their address.

***File Location Parameters***

- **dc_id**         int     Number of the data center holding the file
- **volume_id**     long    Server volume
- **local_id**      int     File ID
- **secret**        long    Checksum to access the file

The problem is I don't know how to generate the `fileid` that is appropriate for bots from `File Location` class.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried to do some reverse engineering. So, I've found out that there is some relation between `File Location` class and `FileId`.

It is my `File Location` **sample** address.

- id:`0`            // This field is only available for secret chats
- access_hash:`0`   // This field is only available for secret chats
- volume_id:    `429640340` (`199BCA94 HEX`)
- secret: `-3528741004939935589` (`CF0764C08833409B HEX`)  // according to TG documentations it should be file CheckSum
- local_id: `6005` (`1775 HEX`)

And this is my according `FileID` to the former `FileLocation` class that I retrieved it from my Bot:

- FileId: `AgADBAADL6gxG06L8w0nhNO87UW3iZTKmxkABJtAM4jAZAfPdRcAAgI`

It is obvious that `FileID` value is in `Base64` format. So I've decoded it:

- HEX Value:
  `0200030400032FA8311B4E8BF30D2784D3BCED45B78994CA9B1900049B403388C06407CF7517000202`

Now we can see the `FileLocation` values in this hex value:

- Unknown: `0200030400032FA8311B4E8BF30D2784D3BCED45B789`
- VolumeId:`94CA9B19 HEX`
- Unknown:`0004`
- Secret: `9B403388C06407CF HEX`
- local_id:`7517 Hex`
- Unknown:`000202`

**NOTE: the values are stored in `Big-Endian` format.**

Now we need to decode `Unknown` values. I appreciate any effort that helps to decode these values.

Comment: It seems there is no relationship between the `PhotoSize.location` from Telegram-API and the `PhotoSize.file_id` from the Bot-API

Answer (score 1):

Here's the TL scheme for bot API file ids: https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/blob/master/src/danog/MadelineProto/TL_botAPI.tl

I have implemented bot API file id conversion in MadelineProto: you basically have to base64decode the file ids, pass them through an RLE decoder based on null byte, and then decode them using the given TL scheme.
See TL/Conversion/BotAPI* to see how MessageMedia objects are converted to a File objects before serialization.

I managed to reverse engineer file ids (I forgot to search here xd) using this [special MTProto bot I built using the same lib](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/blob/master/bots/pwrtelegram_debug_bot.php).

Comment: please post summery of your reverse engineering results here that would be more helpful instead of sharing php code